# Draggable and Resizable DIV doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try implement draggable and resizable DIV elements in same time according to following:
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

It works good when I use one DIV. I can move and resize DIV.

But when I use more than one DIV, it doesn't work good. When I resize one DIV, another automatically change position.

How can I fix it?

I include following links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

I use following JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.yellow').draggable().resizable();
    });
```

I use following CSS:

```
.yellow {
background-color:#f6921e;
background:rgba(246,146,30,0.3);
border-color:#f6921e; 
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:6px;       
border-radius: 6px;
position:inherit;
position:fixed;
```

}

I use following DIV:

```
<div class="yellow" style="top:100px">
</div>
```

Comment: think you can make a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Your question says you have an issue with multiple div. What does the other one look like? Are you using the same class for all of them? If so that would cause some problems...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w2F4v/ - working for me

Comment: Hello all, I use jquery-1.8.3.js, jquery-ui-1.9.2.css and jquery-ui-1.9.2.js . Now It works :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should call the function foreach elem that match your class

http://jsfiddle.net/Rc8S3/3/

jquery

```
$.each($('.yellow'),function(index,elem){$(elem).draggable().resizable();;})
```

css

```
.yellow {
background-color:#f6921e;
background:rgba(246,146,30,0.3);
border-color:#f6921e; 
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:6px;       
border-radius: 6px;
position:inherit;
position:fixed;
}

.red {
background-color:#550000;

border-color:#f6921e; 
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:6px;       
border-radius: 6px;
position:inherit;
position:fixed;
}
```

html

```
<div class="yellow" style="top:100px">
</div> 
<div class="yellow" style="top:200px">
</div>
```

Comment: @user3388636 I know that works with your changes but I thought that should be some problems (maybe I'm wrong)